# how to get only one value from array data and convert it into comma separted values. using javascript without template literals

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string, web

i have array data in the format given below

```
const data=  [
  {
    name: "productname",
    id: "1356",
    price: "0.00",
    category: "Health",
    position: "1",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "20",
    brand: "Health"
  },
  {
    name: "productname2",
    id: "5263",
    price: "0",
    category: "Hair",
    position: "2",
    list: "New Products",
    stocklevel: "",
    brand: "Hair"
  }]
```

from this data i want only product name of each product by difference of product1 , product2.
for example i want the data in format of string by comma separated values like given below:-

```
product1name: "productname",
product2name: "productname2",
...
```

i tried using map function but not able to take only one or two values from whole array data.
here is the code what i tried

```
    var dataByComa = '';

  var Values = data
  .map(function (p, i) {
    return Object.keys(data[i]).map(function (k) {
      return "prod" +" " + ": " + JSON.stringify(data[i][k]);
    });
  }).map(function (v) {
    return v.join(",\n"); });
  var commaValues = Values.join(",\n");
return commaValues;
```

with this code i can able to convert array data into comma separated values but i want only productnames.

**Note** :- Without using template template literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I'm more clear on what the OP was looking for now - here is an answer that fulfills all the requirements

```
let commaValues = ""
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    commaValues += ("product" + (i + 1) + "name: " + "\"" + data[i]["name"] + "\", ")
}
// result: 'product1name: "productname", product2name: "productname2", '
```

Comment: worked!.  thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using reduce. It takes a function as first and an initial value as second parameter (here an empty object {}).
The variable "previous" keeps track of the current state of the (initially empty) new object while the function adds the name of every single Element from the "data" array to the object.

```
var result = data.reduce((previous, element) => {
    previous[element.name] = element.name;
    return previous;
}, {})
```

**EDIT:**
As i realized, you actually want a string as result. In that case you could do:

```
var result = data.reduce((previous, element) => {
    previous[element.name] = element.name;
    return previous;
}, {})
var csvWithBrackets = JSON.stringify(result)
var csv = csvWithBrackets.substring(1, csvWithBrackets.length-1)
```

However the answer from Pzutils seems more compact.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer but as i have mentioned i need data in comma separated values. and your output gives data into array format. help me if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the data and assign the value to an external variable like this:

```
    let finalData = {}
    data.forEach((item, index) => {
       finalData[`product${index+1}name`] = item.name
    })
```

Comment: wrong..! this is an array format, and i want in comma separated values without template literals.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).